# Is it possible to disable AJAX in RichFaces?

Tags: ajax, richfaces, seam

Is it possible in a Seam/RichFaces page to disable AJAX so requests are sent via regular server-client request, where the entire page is refreshed instead of individual elements? I'm using an `a4j:outputPanel` and an `a4j:commandButton` and need to have them not use AJAX in some cases via a toggle button.

Here's a code snippet from the page. Thanks.

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="output" rendered="#{not empty overtime.overtimeItems}" 
    ajaxRendered="true">
  <c:forEach items="#{overtime.overtimeItems}" var="oc">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{oc.dateLabel}"
      style="font-weight:#{(oc.id == 1) ? 'bold' : 'normal'}" 
      for="#{oc.overtimeDateId}" />
    <rich:calendar value="#{oc.overtimeDate}" 
      requiredMessage="Date 1 is required."
      id="#{oc.overtimeDateId}" datePattern="MM-dd-yyyy" 
      required="#{oc.id == 1 ? true : false}" firstWeekDay="0">
      <a4j:support event="onchanged" 
         reRender="#{oc.overtimeHoursId}, #{oc.overtimeHoursOutputId}" 
         ajaxSingle="true"/>
    </rich:calendar>
    ......

  </c:foreach>
</a4j:outputPanel>

<a4j:commandButton action="#{utilities.sendEmail('/pages/overtime/mail.xhtml')}" 
    type="submit" value="Submit" 
    reRender="status, valid1, valid2" eventsQueue="foo" status="status" 
    onclick="this.disabled=false" id="btnSubmit"
    oncomplete="#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null ? 'Richfaces.hideModalPanel(\'mpErrors\');' : 'Richfaces.showModalPanel(\'mpErrors\'); this.disabled=false'}"/>
```

Comment: I've created a version of the page with no a4j components. Couldn't find a way to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to do it is to wrap these ajax components in panelgroups and use the rendered property. You'll basically need to provide conditional rendering and provide non-ajax alternatives of the ajax components.

So you would have something like :

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{someBean.ajaxEnabled}">
    <a4j:commandButton ..... />
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{!someBean.ajaxEnabled}">
    <h:commandButton ..... />
</h:panelGroup>
```